# Bootstrap UI Datepicker block blur event

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap, onblur

I would like to have a excel-like table. I have it for all my fields except for the datepicker (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)
When I double-click the date-field to update it, the datepicker isn't shown even if there is the autofocus on the input-field.
When I choose the date the blur event is triggered but the datepicker doesn't change the value.
If I remove the ng-blur event from the input-field the autofocus works (so if I double click on the field the datepicker appears) and the date changes, but obviously I can't catch the blur event.
The doneEditing function is used to store the changes to the DB and to make the fields editable (showing a span or an input-text).

This is the code:

```
<div style="width: 70px; height:30px" ng-dblclick = "startEditing(item)" ng-hide="item.editing">
<span>{{item.date | date:"dd.MM.yyyy"}</span>
</div>
<form ng-show="item.editing" ng-submit="doneEditing(item)">
<input type="text" ng-focus="focusEditing(item)" ng-blur="doneEditing(item)" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy" ng-model="item.date" required autofocus readonly/>
</form>
```